# Load Select Field with Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

So i'm trying to load a SelectField on a webpage. 
Flask crash when i connect on localhost with a browser. 
With this message: "* Debugger PIN: 320-071-095"

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField, RadioField

from main import mut_infos, year_infos

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "BoomVroom"



class SelYear(FlaskForm):
    years = SelectField(u'year', choices= list(year_infos.keys()),coerce=int)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    form = SelYear()
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

years_infos is a dictionnary taking an integer as key.

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask WebApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.years }}
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**edit:**
On the terminal

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 320-071-095
```

On the web page, it just says it can't find the server
"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site."

Comment: I'm almost certain the debugger gives more feedback than just the pincode? Please post the complete error trail.

Comment: I've edited the post.

Comment: well, that is no crash, that is just ok. What do you use in your browser to open your app? it should be "127.0.0.1:5000" or "localhost:5000" in the address bar and press enter...

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm doing. It works for the other pages, and worked fine when the page was blank. But when i add context in render_template it can't find the server. More exactly, the server ends and the terminal 'gives back the hand' (sorry, not english native).

Comment: Could you show us what the output of this is: choices= list(year_infos.keys()).

Comment: [2009, 2011, 2010, 2016, 2008, 1997, 2006, 1995, 1908, 2005, 2000, 2007, 2012, 1982, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2001, 2004, 1953, 1979, 1907, 1998, 1933, 1949, 2002, 1989, 1987, 1977]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to have a new look at your choicelist. As can be found in the doc, SelectField expects a list of tuples: https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html

choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')]

What you could do is something like this:

```
def choicelist():
    choices = []
    for c in choices # refer to your list of years here
        choices.append((str(c), c)) 

    return choices
```

and point your choices= list(year_infos.keys()) to that choicelist function.